# Is Ajax with JSON or Ajax with dojo are same

Tags: ajax, json

I am new in Ajax . Want to use Ajax with Json . I am searching the tutorial for this and i find [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/).

I want to ask is i am in right direction ?

Is both things are same Ajax with Json and Ajax with dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not the same

Ajax is a technology that send request and accept data asynchronously(do not need to reload page).

You can use JSON or XML to send the data or just use the string.

When you do the Ajax request, any data type(like array, object, number..) except string will lost their data type and become string, so If you want to reserve their type, you must use data transmit format like JSON and XML.

Dojo just a library which have easier method for doing Ajax. You also can use jQuery, Angular,..Whatever even JavaScript native XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Can you please suggest  me best tutorial for Ajax with json for beginner

Comment: Did you use Dojo as library?

Comment: No actually even i don't know the concept

Comment: If you want to know json, you can see here:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_quick_guide.htm

You must to learn ajax and json separately. Learn ajax with your library first, and learn json second.

Comment: Ajax can do without json. you must start from it.